# design pattern query

Tags: oop, design-patterns

i have a question regarding design patterns.

suppose i  want to design pig killing factory

so the ways will be

1) catch pig

2)clean pig

3) kill pig

now since these pigs are supplied to me by a truck driver

now if want to design an application how should i proceed
what i have done is

```
public class killer{  
private Pig pig ;  
public void catchPig(){ //do something };  
public void cleanPig(){ };  
public void killPig(){};  
}
```

now iam thing since i know that the steps will be called in  `catchPig--->cleanPig---->KillPig` manner so i should have an abstract class containing these methods and an execute method calling all these 3 methods.

but i can not have instance of abstract class so i am confused how to implement this.
remenber i have to execute this process for all the pigs that comes in truck.

so my question is what design should i select and which design pattern is best to solve such problems .

Comment: I think it's a vegetarian

Comment: Are you only going to kill pigs or are other animals welcome as well?

Comment: till now will be going for only pigs...my truck driver supplies only pigs(Object)

but yes pigs will be suplied in truck(map)...so should i differentiate my pig killing machine code from  pig coming from truck driver(i am thinking like command pattern design....am i correct)

Comment: I guess the obvious difference is that if the truck driver brings the pig then you can bypass the CatchPig event.

Comment: @ZafKhan...catchPig is just like i am bringing pig to killing..it does not mean that i am going to catch pig from jungle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach than what was suggested here before.

I would do something like this:

```
public abstract class Killer {
   protected Pig pig;

   protected abstract void catchPig();

   protected abstract void cleanPig();

   protected abstract void killPig();

   public void executeKillPig {
       catchPig();
       cleanPig();
       killPig();
   }
}
```

Each kill will extend `Killer` class and will have to implement the abstract methods. The `executeKillPig()` is the same for every sub-class and will always be performed in the order you wanted catch->clean->kill. The abstract methods are protected because they're the inner implementation of the public `executeKillPig`.

Comment: +1. Better than an Interface. Here, the steps will always be performed in the right order. An interface cannot ensure this.  (P.S. this is called the template pattern). Also, expressing intent is important: every sub class IS A `Killer` vis-a-vis with an interface we're allowing any arbitrary class to have the Killer _behavior_. But from a domain design point of view this doesn't make sense. We want to say/emphasise/reinforce in code that every object that does this IS A `Killer`, and certainly not a `Vegetarian`.

Comment: Fist of all you can not assure that having only abstract class. You can only advised/suggest, but when you have abstract class every public/protected method can be changed. The template pattern increase thing coupling so it not best option. IMHO should be avoided. The route that is implemented in template, could be at some point changed, then we need to worry about all classes that implements it. A more agile way is to have some other object that take the killer object and manipulate him as it needs.

Comment: @Vash, I agree that "cannot assure that having ... abstract class". Yes, you can call your `Killer` subclass `Vegetarian` if you want and override methods, but my argument is not about coding mechanics. I _think_ you're getting at an argument of semantics: this answer is explicit about "pigs" not "animals" in general. Nonetheless if the `Killer` class handled `Animal`s instead of `Pig`s then still I would use an abstract base class with a template pattern, not an interface.

Comment: You still are focused on the item not on the concept that i why you try to sell me that I am focused around semantics. My idea was more around the flexibility of execution (usage) what a killer object can do. But this is discussion about who like more what. So the proving something is point less especially when you do not got the point about loose coupling.

Comment: This is what i was doing and honestly speaking i was expecting same thing. this make sense . one minor comment we can have an interface which our abstract class Killer overrides.(and killer can implement just one execute method and leave others for parent classes).

Answer (score 1):

This extends Avi's answer and addresses the comments.

The points of the code:

1. `abstract` base class to emphasize IS A relationships
2. Template pattern to ensure the steps are in the right order
3. Strategy Pattern - an `abstract` class is as much a interface (little "i") as much as a `Interface` (capital "I") is.
4. Extend the base and not use an interface.
5. No coupling of concrete classes. Coupling is not an issue of `abstract` vs `interface` but rather good design.

```
    public abstract Animal {
        public abstract bool Escape(){}
        public abstract string SaySomething(){}
    }

    public Wabbit : Animal {
        public override bool Escape() {//wabbit hopping frantically }
        public override string SaySomething() { return @"What's Up Doc?"; }
    }


    public abstract class Killer {
        protected Animal food;
        protected abstract void Catch(){}
        protected abstract void Kill(){}
        protected abstract void Clean(){}

        protected abstract string Lure(){}

        // this method defines the process: the methods and the order of
        // those calls. Exactly how to do each individual step is left up to sub classes.
        // Even if you define a "PigKiller" interface we need this method
        // ** in the base class ** to make sure all Killer's do it right. 
        // This method is the template (pattern) for subclasses. 
        protected void FeedTheFamily(Animal somethingTasty) {
            food = somethingTasty;
            Catch();
            Kill();
            Clean();
        }

    }
    public class WabbitHunter : Killer {
        protected override Catch() { //wabbit catching technique }
        protected override Kill() { //wabbit killing technique }
        protected override Clean() { //wabbit cleaning technique }
        protected override Lure() { return "Come here you wascuhwy wabbit!"; }

    }

    // client code ********************
    public class AHuntingWeWillGo {
        Killer hunter;
        Animal prey;

        public AHuntingWeWillGo (Killer aHunter, Animal aAnimal) {
            hunter = aHunter;
            prey = aAnimal;
        }

        public void Hunt() {
            if ( !prey.Escape() ) hunter.FeedTheFamily(prey)
        }
    }


    public static void main () {
        // look, ma! no coupling. Because we pass in our objects vice
        // new them up inside the using classes

        Killer ElmerFudd = new WabbitHunter();
        Animal BugsBunny = new Wabbit();
        AHuntingWeWillGo safari = new AHuntingWeWillGo( ElmerFudd, BugsBunny );

        safari.Hunt();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing refer to part of OOP called [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

Instead of abstract class i will be using a interface, the difference between interface an abstract class is that interface have only method descriptors, a abstract class can have also method with implementation.

```
public interface InterfaceOfPigKiller {

  void catchPig(); 
  void cleanPig();
  void killPig();
}
```

In the abstract class we implement two of three available methods, because we assume that those operation are common for every future type that will inherit form our class.

```
public abstract class AbstractPigKiller implements InterfaceOfPigKiller{

  private Ping pig; 

  public void catchPig() {
    //the logic of catching pigs. 
  } 

  public void cleanPig() {
   // the logic of pig cleaning. 
  }

}
```

Now we will create two new classes:

- AnimalKiller - The person responsible for pig death.
- AnimalSaver  - The person responsible for pig release.

---

```
public class AnimalKiller extends AbstractPigKiller { 

 public void killPig() {
   // The killing operation
 }

}

public class AnimalSaver extends AbstractPigKiller {

 public void killPing() {
   // The operation that will make pig free
 }

}
```

---

As we have our structure lets see how it will work.

First the method that will execute the sequence:

```
public void doTheRequiredOperation(InterfaceOfPigKiller killer) {

   killer.catchPig();
   killer.cleanPig();
   killer.killPig();
}
```

As we see in the parameter we do not use class `AnimalKiller` or `AnimalSever`. Instead of that we have the interface. Thank to this operation we can operate on any class that implement used interface.

---

Example 1:

```
public void test() {

  AnimalKiller aKiller = new AnimalKiller();// We create new instance of class AnimalKiller and assign to variable aKiller with is type of `AnimalKilleraKiller `
  AnimalSaver aSaver = new AnimalSaver(); //

  doTheRequiredOperation(aKiller);
  doTheRequiredOperation(aSaver);


}
```

Example 2:

```
public void test() {

  InterfaceOfPigKiller aKiller = new AnimalKiller();// We create new instance of class AnimalKiller and assign to variable aKiller with is type of `InterfaceOfPigKiller `
  InterfaceOfPigKiller aSaver = new AnimalSaver(); //

  doTheRequiredOperation(aKiller);
  doTheRequiredOperation(aSaver);


}
```

---

The code example 1 and 2 are equally in scope of method `doTheRequiredOperation`. The difference is that in we assign once type to type and in the second we assign type to interface.

Conclusion

We **can not create new** object of abstract class or interface but we **can assign** object to interface or class type.

Comment: -1. This is a good example of abuse of interfaces IMHO; and it's muddling polymorphism and inheritance conceptually. There is absolutely no need here for an `abstract` class to implement an interface. The class itself can declare and define the needed methods. Conceptually an interface imbues (limited/specific) _behavior_ giving any object that ability while it _IS_ something else. OTOH the subclass `PigKiller` is a born `Killer` and _inherently_ has all of the `Killer` behavior.

Comment: The interface was introduced to strongly show the concept as using abstract class and class sometimes is to complicated. Imaging that abstract class is something like interface but we can have common implementation is way easier. As the presented example is far from correctness. Your opinion are misguiding. Thee need for abstract class beside above explanation share common action like `catchPig` and `cleanPig`, we left open to child how the would like to deal with pig.  Introducing interface we give change to have some totally different kill.

Comment: @radarbob, This will prevent something like extend abstract and override two from three methods. So abstract classes should be avoided not promoted IMHO. I would not use the abstract class here, but the question required it.